# opening or editing a file quickly?

Tags: files, copy, paste

how can i open a file with along name using leafpad,notepadqq....etc without copying the name and pasting it is there any trick on the keyboard or a command ? thanks on advanced

Beginner

Comment: besides "auto complete" using "tab"?

Comment: yea thats what i mean auto complete the name i tried to hit the tab key and its not working should i install any script for this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Out of what situation do you want to edit what text file?

Comment: @ZiaddHosary nope. It even auto adds "'s when needed. Works out of the box if you use a shell that supports it. What operating system are you using? We are talking command line I hope? What shell are you using? (add those answers into the question please)

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 ,yeah on the command line (Terminal) ,shell that I'm using idk. I'm just a beginner

Comment: Well . . .one could use `find` command to print the full name of the file by searching  for it's part

Comment: @Byte Commander i have along name for a txt file on my Desktop ,I'm wondering if there are a way using the terminal command line to auto complete the name instead copying the name of the file and pasting it

Comment: @ZiaddHosary  But there is already tab completion ! For example when you start typing name of the command , `gedit` , then space , then name of the file - just type 3 - 4 letters and hit TAB key couple of times

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for helping i success doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminal (using the default Bash shell or something similar), you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete commands and path-/filenames.

Just type the first few characters of a file/directory/command and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> once.

If the characters you entered can only be completed to one single valid name, it will do that.
Else it will display all possible options that start with the given few characters.

Comment: As you're a new user, to mark your question as solved, please accept the best answer by clicking on the round grey tick symbol on the left of it. Thank you and welcome!